# Ubuntu Firefox v26 - Geolocation API not working

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, geolocation, ubuntu-12.04

My web app utilizing the Geolocation API works fine in Chrome v32 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but not in FF v26.

The same app works as expected in FF on Android, so I suspect there is an issue with the Ubuntu version.

Are there any know issues?

**Update:**
This thread seems to indicate that the issue persist since FF v24:

[geolocation doesn't work with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632436/geolocation-doesnt-work-with-firefox?rq=1)

I have tried FF nightly, but to no avail.